# Problems loading .csv file into RStudio. EOF within quoted string

Tags: r, csv, import, dataset

when I load this file Chicago_Crimes_2005_to_2007.csv (Link https://www.kaggle.com/currie32/crimes-in-chicago) into RStudio I am always getting an error (Warnmeldung:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,: EOF in Zeichenkette / English: EOF within quoted string) , and not all obervations are included. Do you know how to solve the problem? With the other 3 files I had no problems. I am using this code:

```
c2 = read.csv("Chicago_Crimes_2005_to_2007.csv", header = TRUE)
```

I tried to fix it with this code:

```
c2 = read.csv("Chicago_Crimes_2005_to_2007.csv", header = TRUE, quote = "", row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE).
```

Didnt work out. I tried all answers here in stackoverflow with the same error. Nothing helped. Since 1 week no success. Hope somebody can help me. Working with R in RStudio.

Comment: try reading the file using `data.table::fread()`... my experience it that it sometimes will automatically "repair" strange errors in the source files

Comment: @Wimpel thanks for your help. Tried it but getting this error: `In data.table::fread("Chicago_Crimes_2005_to_2007.csv", header = TRUE) :
  Stopped early on line 533719. Expected 23 fields but found 46. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line:`

Comment: `<<537288,5601758,HN409865,06/16/2007 08:15:00 PM,020XX E 94TH ST,1330,CRIMINAL TRESPASS,TO LAND,OTHER RAILROAD PROP / TRAIN DEPOT,False,False,413,4.0,8.0,48.0,26,1191237.0,1843038.0,2007,04/15/2016 08:55:02 AM,41.724300463,-87.575094193,"(41.724300463, -87.5,ID,Case Number,Date,Block,IUCR,Primary Type,Description,Location Description,Arrest,Domestic,Beat,District,Ward,Community Area,FBI Code,X Coordinate,Y Coordinate,Year,Updated On,Latitude,Longitude,Location>>`

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Also note that "Zeichenkette" is just string, not quoted string. Clarify the error description --- "doesn't work" is not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
require(tidyverse)
df <- readr::read_csv("Chicago_Crimes_2005_to_2007.csv")
```

You may decide to clean up the column names as some have spaces in them, if so:

```
colnames(df) <- c("rowNo",
                   "ID",
                   "Case.Number",
                   "Date",
                   "Block",
                   "IUCR",
                   "Primary.Type",
                   "Description",
                   "Location.Description",
                   "Arrest",
                   "Domestic",
                   "Beat",
                   "District",
                   "Ward",
                   "Community.Area",
                   "FBI.Code",
                   "X.Coordinate",
                   "Y.Coordinate",
                   "Year",
                   "Updated.On",
                   "Latitude",
                   "Longitude",
                   "Location")
```

Comment: I did your code and it was loaded into Rstudio. Also did the column name code. But when I check the dataset all information are only in the rowNo column. Seems that the code didnt seperate all values into the correct columns. So seperation was not successful. What can I do?

Comment: I tried this and now the values are in the correct column, BUT in every 8 or 7th line the values are not correct. they are shifted to the left 2-3 columns. for example the Community.Area Value is inside the X.Coordinate Column and so on. Why?

Comment: can you give me some row numbers that are having that problem?

Comment: This doesn't happen on my computer. It parses perfectly.

Comment: @S002 - check out the data error in line 533,719 of the file, even after it downloads correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of a read script that parses the column names from the first row of the file, cleans them with a combination of `tidyr::gather()` and `gsub()`, and uses them as the input to `read::read_csv()`. It then summarizes the `Row.Number` field to confirm that its maximum value, 6254267 matches the row number from the last row in the file.

```
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
# read first row and clean column names
colNamesData <- read_csv("./data/Chicago_Crimes_2005_to_2007.csv",col_names=FALSE,n_max=1)
# set NA to Row Number
colNamesData[1,1] <- "Row Number"
# use tidyr::gather() to turn rows into columns
xColNames <- gather(colNamesData)
# use gsub() to replace blanks with periods so data can be used as column names
xColNames$value <- gsub(" ",".",xColNames$value)
# read with readr::read_csv() and set column names to data extracted from first row
# skip first row because it contains bad column names and is missing the first column name 
crimeData <- read_csv("./data/Chicago_Crimes_2005_to_2007.csv",col_names=xColNames$value,skip=1)
# last row in file is row number 6254267
summary(crimeData$Row.Number)
```

...and the output:

```
> summary(crimeData$Row.Number)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0  235792  471370 1944429 5601310 6254267 
>
```

**NOTE:** The file does not read all records correctly because at row 533,719 the record appears to end with a redundant list of variable names.

[image]

To correct this, one must either hand edit the data to delete the redundant list of variable names or code around the error.

Interestingly, the row number count restarts at 0 in row 533,720 of the raw data file, which indicates that the people who created this data concatenated multiple files incorrectly to create this data file.